# How to test the layout method in Nuxt (Vue) with jest?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I want to test the "layout" method in a Nuxt page. The structure is as below. I've simplified the code to better serve the question.

```html
<template>

<!-- insert any dom here -->
</template>

<script>

export default {
  layout({ isDesktop }) {
    return `default/${isDesktop ? 'desktop' : 'mobile'}/index`;
  },
  head() {
    return {};
  },
  name: 'PageName',
  meta: {
      anyMetaProperty: true
  },
  data() {
let component = import( `~/path/to/the/child/component`);
    return {
      component,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I've successfully tested other parts of the code since they are similar to typical Vue component, but I had no luck with the "layout" method. I've tried accessing `wrapper.vm.layout` in the test, but it returns undefined. I also have tried mocking the method with `jest.fn()` `mockReturnedValue` function, but the method stays uncovered when I checked the coverage by running `jest --coverage`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you add your test code? i have the same problem, tryin the following code but the variable is empty

    `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();`
    `expect(wrapper.vm.$data.layoutName).toBe('mylayoutname')`

Comment: I cannot share the whole code, but its something similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/c4y9rbqL/